# jQuery UI Dialog not show with different execution flow

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a weird problem with the jquery ui dialog.
i have a rendered page can show 2 type dialogs (confirmation, err).

if i start pop the err dialog, then confirmation, they worked as expected.

but if i start pop the confirmation, then err, the err dialog didn't show up.
i debug the javascript but no err.

i welcome any reply how to troubleshoot/debug as well.

javascript for the dialog:

```
function ConfirmationDialog(strMsg, actionYes) {
    var dlg = $("#ConfirmationDialog");
    dlg.html(strMsg);
    dlg.dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Yes: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                if (actionYes != null) actionYes();
            },
            No: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    }).parent().addClass("ui-state-highlight");
}

function ErrorDialog(strMsg) {
    var dlg = $("#ErrorDialog");
    dlg.html(strMsg);
    dlg.dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    }).parent().addClass("ui-state-error");
}
```

the html:

```
<script src="/xx/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="/xx/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
<script src="/xx/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

<div id="ConfirmationDialog" title="Confirmation" />
<div id="ErrorDialog" title="Error" />

<a href="javascript:ErrorDialog('err');">Err</a>
<a href="javascript:ConfirmationDialog('cc',null);">Confirmation</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it and it worked after I added the closing tags to the div's:

```
<div id="ConfirmationDialog" title="Confirmation"></div>
<div id="ErrorDialog" title="Error"></div>
```

I have also a suggestion for your javascript. Because you select the dialog with

```
var dlg = $("#ErrorDialog");
```

You don't have to do

```
$(this).dialog("close");
```

That will unnecessarily create another object. Just do

```
dlg.dialog("close");
```